# Holding page still showing after I have uploaded the new website

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, browser-cache

I have just uploaded a wordpress website to a live URL which previously displayed a placeholder 'new website coming soon' page.

I have since uploaded the new site which is working fine in Google Chrome however when I try to load it up in Firefox or Edge it still displays the placeholder page.

I have tried clearing the cache for both browsers but the issue still persists!

Is there anything I can do in wordpress or anywhere else to resolve this issue.

The web address is http://www.mascar.co.uk

This is what you should be seeing.

[image]

This is what i am currently seeing.

[image]

I had initially set the home page to be the 'coming soon' page that I created but I have checked this and the home page is now set correctly in the homepage settings menu. Strangely, other pages on the site such as http://www.mascar.co.uk/drivers all seem to load up fine, it's just the homepage.

Update: Chrome on other PCs are showing the old holding page also, simple browser cache won't fix this either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is cache issue, please go to **plugins sections** and un-installed all the cache plugins and then save permalinks from `settings > Permalinks.`

Please access this link http://www.mascar.co.uk/?sadkjfad, its working fine.

If the above steps do not help you to resolved your problems, then go to your root directory and delete your `.htaccess` files and save permalinks again from `settings > Permalinks`.

I hope its help you. :)

Comment: EDIT: This fixed it! Thanks very much! I deleted the .htaccess files in my root folder for the website and re-saved the permalinks

Comment: Before 2 days i have faced with the same issues, and after deleting the .htaccess file its working fine. I just used ?sadkjfad for clear cache . you can use any things like ?jhsgjhasdg. Please clear your server cache also. I am sure that there is an issue of cache.

Comment: Thanks , please mark as an answers arrow. so it helps to other developers also.